# Output Encoding security issue in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, owasp, websecurity

I am working with some legacy web apps, created with ASP.NET Webforms, that are being scanned by using Trustwave. We are using .NET Framework 4.6.

The scan report is showing that we have an output encoding issue, here are some details:

```
Types of encoding detected:
URL encoding

Unencoded injection string: **CENZIC123 !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~\CENZIC456**

Characters that were not encoded in the detection string: !()*-._~
Characters that should have been encoded for URL encoding: ****!()~****

Injection URI: https://mywebsite/Authentication/Login.aspx?CENZIC123%20!%22%23%24%25%26'()*%2B%2C-.%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5B%5D%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~%5CCENZIC456
```

I have tried to fix this by changing the default HTTP encoder to the AntiXss Encoder in the HTTP runtime node inside my Web.Config, as Microsoft documentation suggest. But I still having that issue reported in the scans.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

I've met issue which is somehow similar to yours. The gateway blocked requests that has `'` in querystring. This is not quite related to your sites settings, its reported by security scanner.

Our solution is encoding the querystring to `Base64` and the gateway no more block requets. On client side, you can use `btoa(encodeURIComponent(...))` to encode that string to base64 encoding. On server side, `Convert.FromBase64String(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64String))` will convert it back.